# get data from two tables and collect them in array and count rows of one table result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I had two tables named fixture_list and OneRecord where fixture_list has 3 columns named Team1, Team2, player whereas OneRecord has columns like Team1, Team2, id, status so here I want to select all the data of fixture_list and put them into array whereas I want to count the number of rows based on this where condition fixture_list.Team1=OneRecord.Team1 and
fixture_list.Team2=OneRecord.Team2 from OneRecord, actually I am not able to distinguish between selecting the data and putting it into the array and counting the number of rows because I just want to count the rows of one record only. I know things like joins and mysqli_multi_query() can be performed but do not know how...I want to perform this thing in single query please help.

```
<?php

require_once('connect.php');

$sql = "select * from fixture_list";

if($res = mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
$result = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

array_push($result,
array('players'=>$row[3],
 'team1_name'=>$row[1],
 'team2_name'=>$row[2]
  ));
  }
mysqli_free_result($res);
}
echo json_encode (array("list"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub_query to do this. I don't understand your question perfectly (try using capitals and punctuation marks), but this should be probably the format to use.

```
$sql = "SELECT `fixture_list`.`team1_name`,
               `fixture_list`.`team2_name`,
       (
          SELECT count(`OneRecord`.`Team1`) as `total` 
          FROM `OneRecord`
          WHERE `OneRecord`.`Team1` = `fixture_list`.`Team1`
          AND `OneRecord`.`Team2` = `fixture_list`.`Team2`
       )  as `Total_Players`
FROM `fixture_list`
GROU BY `fixture_list`.`id`";

$result = array(); // keep this outside the while loop to ensure the array is made
if($res = mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $result[] = $row;
  }
}
```

This would give you a $result array as follows:

```
array(
 'team1_name' => 'TEAMNAME1',
 'team2_name' => 'TEAMNAME2',
 'Total_Players'  => INTEGER_VALUE
)
```

The INTEGER_VALUE is the number of rows from the subquery. You can edit the WHERE part of the subquery to your liking

Then you can do this to create a json object:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

This will echo it, which is ideal if you use it with an Ajax function for example.

Comment: which part you did not understand and would you please elaborate your answer so, I could understand.

Comment: I think you need to add `AND  \`OneRecord\`.\`Team2\` = \`fixture_list\`.\`Team2\`` to your `WHERE` clause

Comment: here I do not want to count the rows of the fixture_list, only the rows returned by the sub query from one record , can you show me by editing according to my question

Comment: I would like to add all the results into that array only and the result should include all the rows from fixture_json and number of rows from one record if the where clauses match

Comment: It's still not clear to me, can you give me an example of the final result you would like to have? So an example array structure?

Comment: I want the result into the array because I have to make a JSON finally of all the values in that every row will have the number result which would come from counting the rows of OneRecord, I hope you got the idea

Comment: The list is null all the time

Comment: it is working but there is still a issue, actually it is printing same result two times likes [link](http://www.judgement6.com/judgement_files/fixture_json.php), first in the number format than the name of the coulmns..@Rolfie

Comment: I will alter the code. You must MYSQLI_ASSOC the result and GROUP BY the results.

Comment: The MYSQLI_ASSOC makes sure you don't get a $row[0] = 11 and a $row['id']  = 11. The group by makes sure each row from fixture_list is unique by ID.

Comment: if you see my question i have already defined the array and put data into key -value pairs which is stored in rows, so therefore i only want to encode that nothing else

Comment: I have altered the code again. You can specify the fields you want in the select part of the query. The MYSQLI_ASSOC is necessary to prevent the double values per row. Just add that and you'll be fine. I have to go now, good luck!!

Comment: Well i have got the answer right but still it prints two values one is by ID and other the specific format i have design in the array_push, so therefore please edit the code again when you get time as i want it in the format of array_push only but anyway the work is done but please edit it later, thankyou verymuch my friend..and good bye@Rolfie